# POST variables not persisting from page to page

Tags: php, post

I'm trying to pass variables between consecutive pages of an automated php process.  Because this is automated, I tried setting the variables like this in the prior page:

```
$_POST['index1'] = $variable1;
$_POST['index2'] = $variable2;
$_POST['index3'] = $variable3
$_POST['index4'] = "hard coded string";
```

I also have alert statements printing out these values on the prior page just to make sure they're getting set, which they are.  But when I move to the following page and try to access those variables, I get undefined index errors for all of these variables.  What's happening to the variables from one page to the next that they're not getting passed as expected?

Comment: no, it's not expected that they would pass unless you do so (via a form f.e.). You might want to use `$_SESSION` though.

Comment: How do you "move to the following page"? A redirect? A Hyperlink? A Header?

Comment: It's a redirect using window.location.href inside of a Javascript block.

Comment: `$_POST` is only set if you go to the script using a `POST` request. `window.location.href = ...` uses `GET`, just like entering a URL in the location bar.

Comment: Consider that each request processed by a php script has its own environment. They are strictly separate. So either hand them over via the client as (hidden) form values or use a server side session.

Comment: If they don't pass when I simply set them, how would I make sure they pass?  Since this is an automated process, I don't want to rely on a form.

Comment: Use session variables as @Jeff suggested above.

Comment: Okay, let's say I use session variables.  I'm intending to loop through this process multiple times.  Is it going to be a problem if I'm resetting the session variables each time I go through the loop?

Answer (score -1):

Let's try the following since the information is sensitive.

At the very, very, very, very top of each of the PHP pages connected to this function add:

```
<?    
session_start();
?>
```

Make sure nothing else is above it, no html, no nothing! Otherwise it will mess up whatever you are trying to do.

On the page you were originally setting your `$_POST` variables do the following:

```
$_SESSION["variable1"] = "You";
$_SESSION["variable2"] = "Shall";
$_SESSION["variable3"] = "Not";
$_SESSION["variable4"] = "Pass";
```

You can ofcourse change the "variable1","variable2" and all of its values into whatever you like.

On whichever page you have included

```
<?    
session_start();
?>
```

You can now call echo/print/assign each of the $_SESSION variables you set before by echoing:

```
echo $_SESSION['variable1'];
```

This would produce the following: "You"

This is a more secure way of transferring data (however sessions can still be hijacked unless you're using HTTPS).

Whenever you are done using the data you can simply unset each $_SESSION variable by using either `session_unset();` or `session_destroy();`

I hope this helps!

Comment: Not really, since this information is sensitive, and I don't want to keep it visible in a URL.

Comment: Understood! Will update my answer! Do you have a database readily available?

Comment: I do as a matter of fact.

Comment: Please let me know if this works, disregard the whole database thing!